# It is possible to add a banner indicating there is currently a moderation strike?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderators, community

For "small" or "new" users we are now finding ourselfs as we are not receiving interactions in the website don't knowing why, I would like to proposed adding a **Banner** indicating that **"Currently there is a Moderation Strike, this same Banner will inform you when it will be finally over"**, if you click on it will lead you to [Moderation Strike: Stack Overflow, Inc. cannot consistently ignore, mistreat, and malign its volunteers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389811/1210263)

---

*Don't need to be read - its just to explain my possition. I want to keep this question as short as possible*

I believe many other "small" users like me could relate to this. For low level users is really weird what is happening and we don't really know how this site and the several other related sites of this network works.

I came to Meta for first time just after the strike begin following posts like [Moderation Strike: Stack Overflow, Inc. cannot consistently ignore, mistreat, and malign its volunteers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an) and others: where posts and answers are really long and full of updates, which is also hard to follow for someone is not native in english.

Also I found it by a "happy accident" or I would be still lost in the math network with out knowing why nobody is interacting with me: **as you could see right now, there is no banner telling users about current special situation.**

I hope now you could understand what I aim. I know many will still disagree since is a sensible topic, and many are fairly feeling they have been mistreated, but again, please understand that for many others users like me (small and relativale new), we really don't know what have happened in the past, neither what is going on, so a simple feedback would be the best option to know when the network comes back to normallity.

As also, a banner explaining the strike is still going on will help others to be outside the network supporting in this way the strike as far as it lasts.

This idea born in the following Meta question: [Stack Exchange Moderators in Strike: Please announce here when it is finally over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391292/1210263) (still usefull since there is no banner so far), were I received many downvotes , but I still believe it is a good and fair idea to help those users too small to be relevant on the strike.

Comment: That is something well beyond the control of anyone who is not employed by SE, and SE has a vested interest in *not* advertising the moderator action.  Hence I think that there is no chance that this will happen.  It should be noted that per-site meta posts explaining the strike have been posted across the network, and "featured" on the sidebar.  SE has actively un-featured these posts (though the one for Math SE is still there, on the right).

Comment: @XanderHenderson thanks for the answer. I thought moderators do have that kind of power. I am quite lost with all that is happening right now.

Comment: "... with out knowing why nobody is interacting with me". That's an interesting bit of information to me - thank you for sharing it. And I hope you weren't taking it as something personal about you! I've (almost) entirely stopped participating, but didn't know how much the average user was being affected. And like you, I am eagerly awaiting a settlement so we can get back to discussing math. But I also respect the moderators and their claims, so I'm doing my best to hold off.

Comment: (Also, I up voted this. I know non-employees can't do anything, but I think SE should see what's happening.)

Comment: Can confirm, SE has stated there will be no banner.

Comment: Hi Joako, I've been following www.meta.stackexchange.com for some time. The strike will not end soon, for at least two reasons : (1) The company is very firm on not negotiating right now. That much is clear from recent meta posts, including an invite to some AI-related sessions and another post on the new prompt design site. (2) As a response to this attitude and possibly to prior events, the community's stance has also become firmer. The debate after the strike started with asking for numbers and data and these were given, but after that(might be just me) there is not much new to see.

Comment: The above comment is not very on-topic, I realize that, but after all that I get very mixed feelings about whether everyone should get to know about the strike and really follow it when they are possibly better off giving valuable time to mathematics,se. There is one (~1K reputation with respect to math.se) user who is doing a stellar job over at meta.se, but I don't know how many people will care if someone tells them about this stuff, especially when they realize that there has been no progress in some time (unless there are other links and I'm wrong, very likely this one)

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer What is mathematics.se? I tried to google it and I found nothing related

Comment: @Joako Do forgive me, I meant www.mathematics.stackexchange.com, not mathematics.se. I noticed my mistake much later.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I use MSE for shorthand :)

Comment: @Joako Thank you for correcting me, I will remember to use that from now on. Anyway, the levels of positivity are very low among users that are regularly following/supporting the strike. For them, I will leave the following : any argument against the integration of AI is significantly strengthened when users demonstrate the abilities of an expert : the field of knowledge, the ability to discern the "deeper question" from a not-so-well-formed question, the ability to critique others' proofs and vote by quality, and to reject ill formed and premature questions so as to not confuse people.

Comment: These are the things that we know that an AI still doesn't do very well. On top of that, the prompts need to be given correctly to the interface. All in all, we need to display more facets of being a *human* expert in our writing and thinking if we are to overthrow the incoming wave. Otherwise, we will also have ourselves to blame if many questions have poorly verified and scoped answers in the future, whether those were written by an AI alone or not.

Comment: The only thing the strike has proved so far : the site is OK without mods. Maybe the strike will end by dismissing mods.

Comment: @kludg I disagree... I am a random user and many of my "no so advanved" question have been ignored... kind of simple questions got answers... but if they need some efort you notice that people are not available anymore... at least in MSE

Comment: @Joako - Yeah, I've seen lots of questions that could use a good answer, or clarifying comment, but I'm doing my best to respect the strike. Hopefully they'll settle things soon and we can get back to doing the math.

Comment: @Joako Disagree with what? I don't support the strike and don't support mods. I think the strike is minor internal conflict, and don't believe that mods are doing something good. I think that high-competence humans leaving the site is much more serious problem than stupid AI trolling.

Comment: @kludg in my short experience in MSE I have already noticed that many of those "high-competence humans" that do answer my hard questions (hard for me), are the same guys that are in the firms of the strike (I do look for them), so maybe don't being all of them mods, they do support them so is as they were in the strike context, and they do have stop giving answers or voting.

Comment: @XanderHenderson In [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390704/1210263) is stated that negotiations have concluded... It is going to be now like a poll among moderators in order to stop the strike or not?